# Inconsistent stackmap frames at branch - Java8 Maven Unit Testing

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, javassist, powermockito

First of all I want to mention that I read a lot about this problem and I didn't find any solution.

I have some unit test class, where I use mockstatic method for another class. Then when I run tests it throws "Inconsistent stackmap frames at branch..." error.

I tried all known for me ways e.g. -XX:-UseSplitVerifier or -noverify params added to maven surefire plugin, but none of them works fine. I have all the time the same state.

I tried to change version of PowerMock - older and newest - nothing changed.

I use library:
PowerMockito 1.62 (using Javassist 3.19.0-GA version)
Java 1.8
Maven 3.2.5

Please let me know, is there any working solution how to avoid this problem in Java8+?

Thank's for help!

Comment: `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` does not work with Java 8 anymore. The only solution is to update the tools to versions with correct stackmap support. There were ten years time…

Comment: Which version of maven-surefire-plugin do you use?

Comment: First it was 2.18.1 then I changed it for the last one - 2.19.1. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

Byte code manipulation tools need to update the stack map frames of the code they change. Otherwise, a `VerifierError` is thrown as it is happening in your case. Disabling the validation of the stack map frames by demanding the old verifier (`-XX:-UseSplitVerifier`) is no longer supported in Java 8.

I assume that you uncovered a bug in Javassist which is aware of stack map frames and probably emmits them incorrectly. Try updating to [the latest version](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.javassist%7Cjavassist%7C3.20.0-GA%7Cbundle) of the library. If this does not work, create a reproduction of the error and file a bug.